# How can you tell if a website is hosted on a home server?

Tags: home-server, web-hosting

Are there signs from things like ip address/ports used/etc to tell if a site is hosted on a home server or a high speed commercial server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method might not be foolproof, but it is pretty reliable:

You could check the IP of the site with a reverse DNS check, and see what domain names belong to the IP. If you get results like insertrandomnameorip.provider.com, you know it is a site that is hosted at home.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check hostname/IP in Robtex - http://www.robtex.com/dns/hostname.html or http://www.robtex.com/ip/ip.html